# Overriding Conan Storage directory

Tags: c++, conan

I am trying to use `conan` for a dummy C++ project (language irrelevant here), but I don't like to mess with the user's home directory. By default, `conan install` will use `~/conan/data` as specified by `~/conan/conan.conf`:

```
[storage]
# This is the default path, but you can write your own. It must be an absolute path or a
# path beginning with "~" (if the environment var CONAN_USER_HOME is specified, this directory, even
# with "~/", will be relative to the conan user home, not to the system user home)
path = ~/.conan/data
```

Is there a way to **override the storage directory** to a local one?

I have tried to add a `[storage]` section to a profile I created but apparently `conan` doesn't like it (`ERROR: Error reading './locally' profile: ConfigParser: Unrecognized field 'storage').

Comment: No, storage cannot be specified in profiles. I didn't understand why not changing the storage.path value in the conan.conf file? Did you know about the CONAN_USER_HOME environment variable, that allows to specify where to put the whole local cache? The thing is that in order to locate the conan.conf, it has to exist already in some place defined by convention. Also, what would be the mess? I don't see any problem with storing the binaries there.

Comment: I think `CONAN_USER_HOME` is the way, although I'd prefer a setting in the project configuration.